# Mixing free-tagging, auto-complete and select options in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, jquery-chosen, django-crispy-forms

I'm working on creating forms to encourage users to input keywords and other data.

I've found a great solution for user input of category style data where users select one or more predefined options.

http://renooble.tumblr.com/post/50369942756/displaying-many-to-many-fields-in-django-with
This uses chosen.js and crispy forms.

I would like to know if a similar approach could be used for a free tagging approach, say with keywords. The desired outcome is a similar autocomplete behaviour which autocompletes keywords from a list of suggestions, but which also allows users to enter their own keywords.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the first example from [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) plugin. It seems to do exactly what you want. You haven't specified if the autocomplete result should be pre-defined (as in the example I pointed) or should it be loaded directly from db using ajax.

I think if there's a decent amount of existing tags, then there's no need for ajax, simply pre-fetching data to the frontend should do the trick.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. And I for my case I think there isn't any need for ajax, pre-fetching should do the trick. Thank you so much.